# How to organize SOAP UI test cases

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

In my project , we are testing  web services using SOAP UI tool . Right now this is how the whole project is organized in SOAP UI

1. **Service**

   - **Operation**
   - **Test Steps**
   - **Data Source**

   (Excel Sheet, with all the inputs to operation request and expected results)

   - **Operation**

   (request uses inputs from Data Source above)

   - **Grovey script**

   (which compares expected result from the excel sheet to the operation response)

Right now we have quite a few test scenarios (around 50) in every operation. And SOAP UI iterates through the excel sheet , picks the inputs and checks the response if it is same as expected results (from excel sheet).

Right now because we are maintaining everything in excel , it is not very flexible .

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in this approach and how you would do it if you are in my place.

Comment: Am sure you might have more services. Have a project, create suite for each service and have test case for each operation with same steps as you mentioned except that Test Request would be different for that particular operation. Since you are already using data driven which ok to cover 50 scenarios using one data driven test case. So you will have a excel file for each test case. Approach looks ok to me. Would you please clarify why do you think it is not flexible?

Comment: If everything depends on Excel, you're doing it wrong. Have a look at this: http://www.soapui.org/testing-dojo/best-practices/structuring-your-tests.html